# Font awesome in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I want to use font awesome tags in my javascript code. I am doing this in following way but it is not working.

```
if ($("#showOrderDetail_" + Id).css('display') == 'none') {

    $("#showOrderDetail_" + Id).show();
    $("#viewOrHideDetail_" + Id).html("Hide Details <i class='fa fa- chevron - up' aria-hidden='true'></i>");

} else {

    $("#showOrderDetail_" + Id).hide();
    $("#viewOrHideDetail_" + Id).html("View Details <i class='fa fa- chevron - down' aria-hidden='true'></i>");

}
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary spaces from your class names, should be `fa fa-chevron-up`.

Comment: thanks man.. it solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Class name conn't have space. If you have more than one class then give the each class name with space.

You code must be like this:

```
$("#viewOrHideDetail_" + Id).html("Hide Details <i class='fa fa-chevron-up' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
                                                             ^^^^
                                                             check here
```

The class name is `fa-chevron-up` in font-awesome.

Same for another line also.